# How to find the available EnvDTE.Comands names for Visual Stuadio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I am creating an `Add-In` for `Visual Studio 2010`. Using this Addin I want to add some extra functionality when the user is typing to the editor or copies some text from it.

I searched over the Web to find out what are the command names that Visual Studio executes to add events for these commands. But I didn't find something realy helpful. All I found is some examples and just by luck I saw that the `copy-command` name is *"Edit.Copy"*.

Is there a way to print all available commands from Visual Studio? Any useful link will be very helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to print the commands with the following code:

```
private void EnumerateCommads()
{
    foreach (Command command in _applicationObject.Commands)
    {
        //print command
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to know another solution without code, you can go to Tools\Options\Environment\Keyboard